A Riesz potential inequality in "Elliptic Partial Differential Equations of Second Order"
Gilbarg & Trudinger's "Elliptic Partial Differential Equations of Second Order", page 165-166, Lemma 7.20.
Lemma 7.20. Let $f \in M^p(\Omega)(p>1)$ and $g = V_\mu f, \mu = p^{-1}$. Then there exist constants $c_1,c_2$ depending only on $n$ and $p$ such that
$$\int_{\Omega}\exp \left(\frac{|g|}{c_1K}\right)dx \leq c_2(\text{diam} \Omega)^n$$
where $K = ||f||_{M^p(\Omega)}$.
In the proof, we want to estimate $\int_{\Omega}V_{\mu/q} |f(x)|dx$, where $V_{\mu/q}f(x)$ is Riesz potential. The book shows that
$$\int_{\Omega}V_{\mu/q}|f(x)|dx \leq pq \omega_n^{1-\frac{1}{pq}}|\Omega|^{\frac{1}{pq}}||f||_1.$$
The author also remind to use the Lemma 7.12.
Lemma 7.12. The operator $V_\mu$ maps $L^p(\Omega)$ continously into $L^q(\Omega)$ for any $q,1 \leq q\leq\infty$ satisfying
$$0 \leq \delta = \delta(p,q) = p^{-1}-q^{-1}<\mu,$$
Futhemore, for any $f \in L^p(\Omega)$,
$$||V_\mu f||_q \leq \left(\dfrac{1-\delta}{\mu -\delta}\right)^{1-\delta}\omega_n^{1-\mu}|\Omega|^{\mu-\delta}||f||_p.$$
But we can only get
$$||V_{\mu/q}f||_{q} \leq \left(\frac{pq+p-q}{1+p-q}\right)^{1-1/p+1/q}\omega_n^{1-1/pq}|\Omega|^{1/pq-1/p+1/q}||f||_p$$
My question is how to get the $||V_{\mu/q}f||_1,||f||_1$ and how to handle the parameter to make the inequality hold.
